# Need help on variable COUNT query

Tags: php, mysql, variables, zend-framework, count

I have the below function in my model.  I have a table called item_like.  In that table, I have two columns - saturn_1 and like_id.  I want to get the total count of like_id when saturn_1 is equals the value of 'id' => $item->id in my array.  Am pretty new to coding and can't figure out what is wrong.

Tx for your help.

```
public static function formatCallbackChallenge($item, $template = 'challenges') {
    static $extensions = null;
    if($extensions === null) {
        $extensions = Extensions_Model_Front::getByMethod('item_list');
    }

    $item_title = (strlen($item->title) > 25) ? substr($item->title, 0, 25) . '...' : $item->title;

    $db = JO_Db::getDefaultAdapter();
    $total_likes = new JO_Db_Expr('(SELECT COUNT(like_id) FROM item_like WHERE item = $item->id LIMIT 1)');


    $data = array(
        'template' => $template,
        'sql_row' => isset($item->sql_row) ? $item->sql_row : null,,
        'id' => $item->id,
        'title' => $item_title,
        'total_likes' => $total_likes,
    );



    if($extensions) {
        $front = JO_Front::getInstance();
        foreach($extensions AS $id => $ext) {
            $data_ext = call_user_func(array($front->formatModuleName($ext . '_model_item'), 'listing'), $data, $item);
            if($data_ext && is_array($data_ext)) {
                $data = array_merge($data, $data_ext);
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which database library you're using, and I'm assuming the query runs but returns the wrong data... Base on what you're looking for I see two errors...

1. A PHP error, the $item->id will not be parsed inside of single quoted PHP.
2. LIMIT 1 is redundant, and may cause a problem.

Rewrite the 9th line inside of the method to this:

```
$total_likes = new JO_Db_Expr("SELECT COUNT(like_id) FROM item_like WHERE item = {$item->id}");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Frank.  When I plug in your code on line 9, the page returns "[object Object]".     ----   I am using mysql.  When I dump the db, the top line says: MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.71, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64).  I presume this means the library is redhat?  Any additional help is appreciated.

Comment: That is a javascript response. What's returned will be a PHP object or possibly an array depending on how the library handles it. Do a var_dump() on the response and you'll see how you need to reference the count.

Comment: Thanks Frank.  Actually, it is all within an Ajax call so, yes, it would be javascript response, I think.  Know anything about counts within ajax?